# Zooming in fabricjs, object positions

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a problem ( i believe it is similar to the one calcOffset is fixing) with positions of objects.

I zoom in-out with mouse scroll wheel. After zooming, shapes are displayed at new positions but cannot be handled at these position. Only at their pre-zoom positions.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/w5NjC/)

Here is my code for zooming:

```
function displaywheel(e){
    var SCALE_FACTOR = 1.1;
    var evt=window.event || e
    var delta=evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta
    var objects = canvas.getObjects();
    var dd = 1;
    if (delta == 120) dd=SCALE_FACTOR;
    if (delta == -120) dd=1/SCALE_FACTOR;
    globscale = globscale * dd;
    for (var i in objects) {
        objects[i].setCoords;
        objects[i].scaleX = globscale;
        objects[i].scaleY = globscale;
        objects[i].left = objects[i].left * dd;
        objects[i].top = objects[i].top * dd;
        objects[i].setCoords;
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.calcOffset();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setCoords` [is a function](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setCoords), you need to call it like this:

`objects[i].setCoords();`

`objects[i].setCoords;` does absolutely nothing.

http://jsfiddle.net/w5NjC/1/

Comment: The initial fiddle was not working for Mozilla. Fixed in this -
http://jsfiddle.net/lakshaydulani/L8Lzc/
Credits to original code.

Comment: and he does not need to call setCoords twice in a loop. Last one is enough